# What should I eat so I'm not feeling hungry anymore while consuming as few calories as possible?

Tags: diet, nutrition

I'm looking to lose some percent of body fat again but the biggest problem I face is that I'm hungry all the time. I'm still working out 5 days a week by the way.

This is what I'm looking for:

- Get rid of any appetite or hunger.
- Consume as few calories as possible.
- It's fine if it contains a lot of protein.

What should I eat?

Comment: The best way to reduce hunger and limit calories is to fast. Also, off-topic, so voting to close.

Comment: After that, 15% protein, followed by as much barely processed fat (not seed oils) as you can handle and as few carbs as you can get away with.

Comment: @michael How is this off topic?

Comment: Questions on nutrition are off-topic unless they relate directly to exercise. See: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4):

Intermittant fasting works well. Caffiene is a appatite suppressant so black coffee or a cup of tea could be helpful.

I find the following advice to be most helpful:

*"If you are hungry, drink a glass of water, if you are still hungry then consider eating an apple. If you are not hungry enough to deal with eating a apple then you aren't truly hungry. If you are, then eat the apple."*

Answer (score 2):

First, regarding schedule, I'd recommend you to consider adapting the [intermittent fasting](http://jamesclear.com/the-beginners-guide-to-intermittent-fasting) method. Since I began to eat according to it, my hunger became much easier to handle as I am not much hungry during the fasted state and my meals became biggers.

Regarding food, the answer is vegtables. They are rich in fibers and have low glicemic index, therefore helps your feel sated for a relatively long period. The choice of which vegtables to consume is not crucial, but try to primarily plan on on green ones (lettuce, cucumbers, etc). The best way would be probably preparing a homemade salad with some high-protein food added (chicken breast, tuna, etc).